# Modify value in dictionary

Tags: python

I want to add 1 to every value in the dictionary

```
def increase_by_one(d):
    d = {}
    for value in d:
        d[value] = d[value] + 1
```

This is my code and when i tried to `print(increase_by_one({'first':27, 'second':16, 'third':8})` I get none but i am suppose to get `{'first':28, 'second':17, 'third':9}`.

And also will my code work for this case `increase_by_one({2:{ }, 3:{ }, 4:{ }})` where it will return `{2:{ }, 3:{ }, 4:{ }}`

Comment: Increase keys or values?

Comment: you should not overwrite the `dict` value when you enter the `increase_by_one`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a `None` because your function returns nothing and you're overwriting `d` every time you enter the function.

Fix it by returning the `d`.

```
def increase_by_one(d):
    for key in d:
        d[key] = d[key] + 1
    return d

>>> increase_by_one({'first':27, 'second':16, 'third':8})
{'first': 28, 'second': 17, 'third': 9}
```

If you have nested dictionaries, such as:

```
{'first':27, 'second':16, 'third':8, 'fourth': {'fifth': 28, 'sixth': {'seventh': 29}}}
```

Then you will have to recurse into each sub dictionary. A common approach is to use [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29). An iterative version would have to try to add 1 to the value, catch the exception, enter the dictionary, attempt again.. and so forth.

Comment: However if u were to take away the d = {} there's an error in python that says "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'int'"\   @msvalkon

Comment: Yes, you will not be able to sum together a dictionary and an integer. Please see the edit about nested dictionaries.

Comment: Yes i have a nested dictionary. So how do I abstract out each dictionary ??

Comment: We are only taught the for loop

Comment: Try to solve the problem using recursion. If you encounter a specific problem, open a new question.

Comment: Here's a hint: You will need to add exactly three lines of code. Try, except and a function call.

Answer (score 1):

`d = {}` makes your parameter refers to a new empty `dict`, and your function returns nothing. You need to return the modified `dict` to make print work:

```
def increase_by_one(d):
    ...:     for key in d:
    ...:         d[key] = d[key] + 1
    ...:     return d

print(increase_by_one({'first':27, 'second':16, 'third':8}))
{'second': 17, 'third': 9, 'first': 28}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def add_to_values(d, n=1):
    """Recursively adds n to dictionary values, if possible (in-place)"""
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            add_to_values(value, n)
        else:
            try:
                d[key] += n
            except TypeError:
                continue
```

Comment: You can skip the `isinstance`-check and just `d[key] = add_to_values(value, n)` in place of the `continue` in the `TypeError`.

Comment: what if `value` is a list? you can't `list.items()` ;)

Comment: It's pretty clear this is homework with a very specific problem. There are no lists involved.

Comment: but there might be other looking for solution. No point in making obviously flawed function only to spare two lines of code.