# Increasing values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a function which can take in a dictionary and modify the dictionary by increasing only the values in it by 1?

i.e

```
f({'1':0.3, '11':2, '111':{'a':7, 't':2}})
```

becomes

```
{'1':1.3, '11':3, '111':{'a':8, 't':3}}
```

and

`f({'a':{'b':{'c':5}}})`

becomes

```
{'a':{'b':{'c':6}}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't a built-in function `dictionary_value_one_adder`! Have you tried to implement it at all?

Comment: is it your homework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655674/modify-value-in-dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Not the best...

```
def incr(d):
    try:
        return d + 1
    except TypeError: # test the type rather catch error
        return g_incr(d)
    except:
        return 0
def g_incr(d):
    return {k:incr(v) for k, v in d.items()}


test = {'1':0.3, '11':2, '111':{'a':7, 't':2}}
print g_incr(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this;

```
def increment(dict):
    return {k:v+1 for k,v in dict.items()}
result = increment()
print result
```