# Modify value in nested dictionary

Tags: python

This is my code

```
def increase_by_one(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if d[value] == type(int): ## There is an error here
            d[value] = d[value] + 1
        else:
            d[key] += 1
    return d
```

I am not sure what is wrong. But I am sure it's `if d[value] == type(int)` that is wrong. How can I change it ?

Input

```
increase_by_one({'a':{'b':{'c':10}}})
```

Output

```
{'a':{'b':{'c':11}}}
```

Input

```
increase_by_one({'1':2.7, '11':16, '111':{'a':5, 't':8}})
```

Output

```
{'1':3.7, '11':17, '111':{'a':6, 't':9}}
```

Comment: `d[key]` holds the value, not `d[value]`

Comment: hint: `type(int) == type` and `type(aNumber) == int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655674/modify-value-in-dictionary/22655785#22655785), here's my answer fixed to provide the solution you want:

```
def increase_by_one(d):
    for key in d:
        try:
            d[key] += 1
        except TypeError:
            d[key] = increase_by_one(d[key])
    return d
```

Every time you try to add 1 to a dictionary, a `TypeError` is raised. Since you know you're dealing with nested dictionaries, you call your function again. This is called recursion.

```
>>> increase_by_one({'a':{'b':{'c':10}}})
{'a': {'b': {'c': 11}}}

>>> increase_by_one({'1':2.7, '11':16, '111':{'a':5, 't':8}})
{'1': 3.7, '11': 17, '111': {'a': 6, 't': 9}}
```

Comment: I haven't be taught try: and except TypeError: May I know how it works ? and also even though the 1 is added to values but I realise that for {'first':27, 'second':16, 'third':8}  when i pass it through the function {'first': 28, 'third': 9, 'second': 17} is returned and there is a change in the order of the key. May I know why ?

Comment: You can teach yourself by reading about [handling exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). Dictionaries are *unordered* data structures, you cannot depend on them for order. If order is necessary, we have the [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Answer (score 1):

First of all use `isinstance()` and `iteritems()`

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():

    if isinstance(value,int):
        ...
```

But as you are dealing with nested dicts this won't do. Either use recursion or if you know the depth of your dict, first do a check like `isinstance(value,dict)`

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing by value, but you should be using the key and no need to get the value from the dictionary since you are already using `items()`:

```
def increase_by_one(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if type(value) == int:
            d[key] = value + 1
        else:
            increase_by_one(value) # if you want recursion
    return d
```